# dropdownlist does not retain values after postback if it is inside formview and is populated at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I need help figuring out why some controls that are inside a formview and are filled at runtime lose their contents after postback.

I have a dropdownlist (ddl_1) that I populate based on entries from another dropdownlist (ddl_2) in the same formview. All seem to work fine util a postback event occurs after which, the newly populated dropdownlist (ddl_1) is empty.

The EnableViewState for both these ddls is set to true. ddl_2 is databound but ddl_1 is not. In Page_Load in IsPostBack clause, ddl_2 is databound and then I call the function that populates ddl_1.

If I move ddl_1 outside of the formview, it retains its entries after postback just fine.

Another similar issue is with a TextBox inside the formview. When in insert mode, the contents of the TextBox disappear after postback. This does not happen in insert mode though.

What is specific to formview that causes this?

Thanks much.

Here is the Page_load code.

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        If NavHelper.User.UserName = "" Then
            Dim UserIP As String
            Dim UserLogin As String
            Dim UserEmail As String
            UserIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
            UserLogin = HttpContext.Current.Session("Username")
            UserEmail = HttpContext.Current.Session("Email")
            GetUserInfo()

            CurrentRFQ = Nothing
            If NavHelper.RFQ.ID = -1 Then
                formview_RFQ.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
                tabpanelCustomerParts.Visible = False
                tabpanelDocuments.Visible = False
                tabpanelReviews.Visible = False
                tabpanelRFQReviewHistory.Visible = False
                listview_CustomerParts.Dispose()

            Else
                formview_RFQ.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
                listview_ReviewContracts_Initial.EditIndex = 0
                SessionHelper.CurrentObject = TAA.Library.RFQ.GetObject(NavHelper.RFQ.ID)
                mRFQ = DirectCast(SessionHelper.CurrentObject, TAA.Library.RFQ)
                Dim UserdeptTotal As Long
                UserdeptTotal = HttpContext.Current.Session("DepartmentTotal")
                If formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList") IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList"), DropDownList)
                    FillCompanyNameDropDownList(ddl)
                End If
                tabpanelCustomerParts.Visible = True
                tabpanelDocuments.Visible = True
                tabpanelReviews.Visible = True
                tabpanelRFQReviewHistory.Visible = True
                If NavHelper.RFQ.Copy = True Then
                    SetModifyCopy()
                End If
            End If
        Else    'IsPostBack
            datasource_BuyerNVList.Dispose()
            datasource_BuyerNVList.DataBind()               
            Dim ddl As DropDownList
            If (formview_RFQ.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert) Then
                ddl = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVListInsert"), DropDownList)
            ElseIf formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList") IsNot Nothing Then
                ddl = DirectCast(formview_RFQ.FindControl("ddlCompanyBuyerNVList"), DropDownList)
            End If
            FillCompanyNameDropDownList(ddl)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your `Page_Load` code.

Answer (score 0):

While binding the dropdown use the IsPostback option.

```
if (!IsPostback)
{
   BindDropdown1();
   BindDropdown2();
}
```

This will retain your state. If you are not using ispostback every time the dropdown will be binded when ever you refresh the page. So use ispostback for binding dropdown for the first time.

Comment: but only one of the ddls is bound. Are you saying I need the call DataBind for the bound ddl and based on that populate the other ddl in both IsPostBack and !IsPostBack cases? I just posted my Page_Load code. Can you please point to where/what I should add there? Thx